# Getting Failed while calling GetEvents from postgresqlprovider

Tags: audit.net

IEnumerable events = provider.EnumerateEvents("EventData #> '{Environment,UserName}' = '"abc"'");

Comment: Please add more context and specify the exact error you get

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.